# Do I report gross income or the total after taxes when reporting earnings?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction, social-security

When reporting to the Social Security Administration do I report gross income or the total after tax deductions? I will be holding the amount for taxes until "tax season". I report monthly to the SSA and they withhold certain benefits depending on the amount I earn.

Comment: By "tax deductions" do you mean "tax withholdings"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're taking about [SSI Wage Reporting](https://www.ssa.gov/benefits/ssi/wage-reporting.html), then you would report wages before tax withholdings (and before other payroll deductions):

> If you receive Supplemental Security Income (SSI) and you or your deemor (e.g. your ineligible spouse or parent(s) with whom you live) work, then either you or your representative payee must report the **gross wages** to Social Security. You should consistently report wages during the first six days of the month to help prevent overpayments and underpayments.

Comment: I looked but couldn't find that page you linked to. Thanks. I've up-voted you for the correct answer. Enjoy...!